# Intermittent Auto-Swap?

Tags: azure-deployment

I have a Azure App Service Deploy task (version 3) defined in a VSTS pipeline that is designated to deploy to a non-production slot.  Occasionally, it deploys to the production slot. It seems to be auto swapping intermittently.  But, I can't find the auto-swap feature in the slot's application settings.  Has this feature been removed?